# Expression evaluation from infix to postfix

Tags: c++, stack, operation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;
float postix_evalute(string expr)
{
    stack<float> stk;
    float val;
    for (int x = 0; x < expr.length(); x++)
    {
        if (isdigit(expr[x]))
        {
            stk.push((expr[x] - '0'));
        }
        else
        {
            float op2 = expr[x];
            stk.pop();
            float op1 = expr[x];
            stk.top();
            switch (expr[x])
            {
            case '+':
                val = op1 + op2;
                break;
            case '-':
                val = op1 - op2;
                break;
            case '*':
                val = op1 * op2;
                break;
            case '/':
                val = op1 / op2;
                break;
            }
            stk.push(val);
        }
    }
    return stk.top();
}
int main()
{
    string line;
    cout << "The Value Of experssion" << endl;
    cin >> line;
    cout << postix_evalute(line) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code to get postfix-evalue for string which user enter put when i try to run this code it give me random value not give me the right answer so i want to know what is the problem for example when i enter 32+ it give me 86

Comment: Please provide some sample input, the result you got, and what you expected. Nobody wants to run an interactive program and guess what you typed, when you could just have specified it in the first place.

Comment: @Useless done..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        if (isdigit(expr[x]))
        {
            stk.push((expr[x] - '0'));
        }
```

You're pushing individual digits one at a time. If you run `postfix_evaluate("32")`, this loop will push `3` onto the stack first, and then `2`. Are you sure you don't want the single value `32` on the stack instead?

You can, and should, debug this basic stuff before you write lots of code on a wobbly foundation.

```
            float op2 = expr[x];
            stk.pop();
```

These lines copy a single character from the string (which we've just decided is *not* a digit), promote it to a `float`, and then discard the top of the stack without examining it at all.

For example, if the char is `'+'` (and your encoding is ASCII), you'll have `op2 = 43.0`. You have the same problem with `op1`.

Comment: thanks a lot @Useless for your help  I understand what you mean \

Answer (score 0):

The problems is that you don't pop values from the stack. Or at least you don't use the values form the stack, which you pop only once and not twice.

Instead you get the values from the string, so the values of `op1` and `op2` are the encoded values of the operator you work on.

You need to get the values from the stack:

```
float op2 = stk.top();
stk.pop();
float op1 = stk.top();
stk.pop();
```

Comment: thanks alot for your help :)